# Angular 2: *ngFor list of directives

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-directives

I have a Queue, which itself has an array of People. From within Queue, I would like to display each Person as defined in the person template.

**queue.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Person} from '../person/person';
@Component({
    selector: 'queue',
    directives: [Person],
    template: `<div class="queue">
        <person *ngFor="#tP of people"></person>
    </div>`
})
export class Queue {
    people = [];
    constructor(){
        this.addPerson(new Person("Bob",20));
        this.addPerson(new Person("Jane",30));
        this.addPerson(new Person("Dog",40));
        this.addPerson(new Person("Cat",50));

    };
    addPerson(tP:Person):void
    {
        this.people.push(tP);
    }
}
```

**person.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'person',
    template: `<div class="person">
        <div class="name">{{name}}</div>
        <div class="age">{{age}}</div>
    </div>`
})
export class Person {
    constructor(public name:string = "", public age:number = 5){};
    setName(newName:string):void{
        this.name = newName;
    }
}
```

**What I hope for**

```
<div class="queue">
<div class="person"><div class="name">Bob</div><div class="age">20</div></div>
<div class="person"><div class="name">Jane</div><div class="age">30</div></div>
<div class="person"><div class="name">Dog</div><div class="age">40</div></div>
<div class="person"><div class="name">Cat</div><div class="age">50</div></div>
</div>
```

**What I get**

EXCEPTION: No provider for String! (Person -> String) in [people in Queue@1:16]

**Summary**

I would like to render a list of directives using the template as defined by the directive itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
<person *ngFor="let tP of people"></person>
```

already creates a new person for each item in `people`. Instead you should just add the data to `people = [];` and then use binding to pass the data into the component.

```
constructor(){
    this.addPerson({name: "Bob", age: 20});
    this.addPerson({name: "Jane", age: 30});
    this.addPerson({name: "Dog", age: 40});
    this.addPerson({name: "Cat", age: 50});

};
```

```
<person *ngFor="let tP of people" [name]="tp.name" [age]="tp.age"></person>
```

```
export class Person {
  @Input() name:string;
  @Input() age:number;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('name: ' + this.name + ', age: ' + this.age);
  }
}
```

You usually don't create instances of components yourself, you instruct Angular to do it for you.

If a component has constructor parameters, Angular looks them up in providers lists and creates instances itself to pass them to the constructor. Your error message results from that because Angular doesn't have a provider for `string`. (`constructor(public name:string = "",`)

Comment: Hey thanks for your detailed response. So with this solution the parent queue has an array of Objects instead of Person's and then has to explicitly pass all of the required properties to the <person> it creates via *ngFor? If this is the only way, fine, (and I don't want to detract from your help) but to me it seems like a lot of duplication and it relies on the parent being aware of what the child needs to render. Ideally I want the parent to say to the child "Oi, render yourself!" and the child does the rest because all of it's details are set.

Comment: Regarding the string provider issue, by my understanding I should be able to pass a string in the constructor, as seen here - https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-adding-a-data-model - at around the 1 minute mark

Comment: That's a model class that is not managed by Angular. The class is used as a simple container for data, not as a component and not even as a service and only instantiated by code written by you.